# Deserialize Json objects with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize an object with Json.net. I was able to do it successfully but its more of a hack so I'm looking for a better/proper way to do so.

```
{
"page":"admin",
"context":"id",
"records":{
            "rCount":6,
            "1":[
               {
                  "name":"Romeo",
                  "dob":"01\/01\/1970"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Harry",
                  "dob":"10\/10\/2012"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Lee",
                  "dob":"17\/10\/2012"
               }],
            "2":[
               {
                  "name":"Mark",
                  "dob":"01\/01\/1970"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Jack",
                  "dob":"10\/10\/2012"
               },
               {
                  "name":"Json",
                  "dob":"17\/10\/2012"
               }],

}}
```

this is the json string the issue is with the **records** object. if it doesn't have that **rCount** variable then it can be deserialized as a Dictionary but because of the **rCount** variable it can't be deserialized properly as a dictionary. What should be the proper way of deserialzing this object.

Here is my Solution:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var recordFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecordFile>(Properties.Resources.data);
}

public class RecordFile
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public Records Records { get; set; }
}

public class Records
{
    public int RCount { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private Dictionary<string, object> _reocordList;

    public List<Record[]> RecordList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_reocordList != null && _reocordList.Count > 0)
            {
                return _reocordList.Values.Select(record => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record[]>(record.ToString())).ToList();
            }
            return new List<Record[]>();
        }
    }

}

public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker there is no other way to deseialize it. I'm using **Dictionary<string, object>** because of the **JsonExtensionDataAttribute**. **List<Record[]>** or **Dictionary<string, Record[]>** will do the job

Comment: Yeah, I realized that right after I posted my comment, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **jObject** to manually parse JSON:

```
public class RecordFile
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public Records Records { get; set; }
}

public class Records
{
    public int RCount { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, List<Record>> RecordsDictionary { get; set; } 
}


public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(\* your json *\);
var recordFile = new RecordFile
{
    Page = jObject.Value<string>("page"),
    Context = jObject.Value<string>("context"),
    Records = new Records
    {
        RCount = jObject["records"].Value<int>("rCount"),
        RecordsDictionary =
            jObject["records"].Children<JProperty>()
                              .Where(prop => prop.Name != "rCount")
                              .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name),
                                            prop =>
                                            prop.Value.ToObject<List<Record>>())
    }

};
```

Of course it can be easily to handle cases, when property is not present.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to get rid of the `Records` class completely, ending up with something like this:

```
public class RecordFile
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Record[]> Records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
}
```

Since you don't care *at all* about the `records.rCount` property from the JSON, you could specify a new error handler to simply ignore the property:

```
var recordFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecordFile>(
    jsonString, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    {
        Error = (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.ErrorContext.Path == "records.rCount")
            {
                // Ignore the error
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Now when an error is encountered with the property in question, the deserializer will just skip over it. Another option would be to write a custom converter, but that feels like overkill just to ignore one property.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/3svPqk

Answer (score 1):

The other answers posted so far should both work.  For completeness, I'll show how you can use a custom `JsonConverter` to solve this and also simplify your model a bit.

Here is the code for the converter:

```
class RecordFileConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(RecordFile));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        RecordFile rf = new RecordFile();
        rf.Page = (string)jo["page"];
        rf.Context = (string)jo["context"];
        JObject records = (JObject)jo["records"];
        rf.RecordCount = (int)records["rCount"];
        rf.Records = records.Properties()
                            .Where(p => p.Name != "rCount")
                            .Select(p => p.Value.ToObject<Record[]>())
                            .ToList();
        return rf;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To work with the converter, change your model classes as shown below.  (Notice that the `RecordFile` class has a `JsonConverter` attribute to link the custom `RecordFileConverter` to it.  Also notice the `Records` class is deleted, while the `RCount` and `RecordList` properties have been moved up to the `RecordFile` class and renamed.)

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(RecordFileConverter))]
public class RecordFile
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    public List<Record[]> Records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize as normal:

```
var recordFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecordFile>(json);
```

**Demo**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jz3zUT